# Why does the elif statement not apply when self.Input == 0 and the code stops appending "0" to self.binaryList?

Tags: python, if-statement

So I am relatively new to python and I am trying to build a Binary code converter. The code works fine until `self.Input == 0` and the elif statement seems not to get called. Genereally I have the problem that the last few 0 are not being appended to my self.binaryList after the last 1 in the binary code.

```
class BinaryCode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.twoSquaredList = [256, 126, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
        self.Input = int(input("Number to convert:"))
        self.binaryList = []
        self.x = 9

    def find_number_below_input(self):
        while self.x > 0:
            for number in self.twoSquaredList:
                if number <= self.Input:
                    self.binaryList.append("1")
                    print(self.binaryList)
                    print(number,"number")
                    self.Input -= number
                    print(self.Input,"self.Input")

                elif number > self.Input and len(self.binaryList) > 1:
                    self.binaryList.append("0")

        self.x -= 1
```

This is the output:

```
Number to convert:100
['1']
64 number
36 self.Input
['1', '1']
32 number
4 self.Input
['1', '1', '0', '0', '1']
4 number
0 self.Input
```

Comment: Well, it mostly works but you just don't print your list after the loop.
(Mostly since this while loop on self.x seems out of place.)

Comment: By the way, I assume you do that for learning purposes. If not, you should check the built-in [`bin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin).